# Can you create an index in the CREATE TABLE definition?

Tags: postgresql

I want to add indexes to some of the columns in a table on creation. Is there are way to add them to the CREATE TABLE definition or do I have to add them afterward with another query?

```
CREATE INDEX reply_user_id ON reply USING btree (user_id);
```

Answer (score 171, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any way of specifying an index in the `CREATE TABLE` syntax. PostgreSQL does however create an index for unique constraints and primary keys by default, as described in [this note](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-NOTES):

> PostgreSQL automatically creates an index for each unique constraint and primary key constraint to enforce uniqueness.

Other than that, if you want a non-unique index, you will need to create it yourself in a separate `CREATE INDEX` query.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the unique constraint creating an index.

Comment: Note that PostgreSQL supports transactional schema updates - it's a good idea to BEGIN/COMMIT around your CREATE TABLE and CREATE INDEX statements, if you want the net overall table creation to succeed or fail as a whole.

Answer (score 31):

No.

However, you can create `unique` indexes in the create, but that's because they are classed as *constraints*. You can't create a "general" index.

Answer (score 29):

> Peter Krauss is looking for a canonical answer:
>
> There are a MODERN SYNTAX (year 2020), so please explain and show examples, compatible with postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html

You are searching for **inline index definition**, which is not available for PostgreSQL up to current version 12. Except UNIQUE/PRIMARY KEY constraint, that creates underlying index for you.

[CREATE TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/sql-createtable.html)

> [ CONSTRAINT constraint_name ]
>   { CHECK ( expression ) [ NO INHERIT ] |
>     UNIQUE ( column_name [, ... ] ) index_parameters |
>     PRIMARY KEY ( column_name [, ... ] ) index_parameters |

---

The sample syntax of inline column definition(here SQL Server):

```
CREATE TABLE tab(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,                            -- constraint
  c INT INDEX filtered (c) WHERE c > 10,         -- filtered index
  b VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL INDEX idx_tab_b,        -- index on column
  d VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  INDEX my_index NONCLUSTERED(d)                 -- index on column as separate entry
);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2e79ca87fc915202d107e2970c4165fe)**

The rationale behind introducing them is quite interesting [What are Inline Indexes? by Phil Factor](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/what-are-inline-indexes/)

Comment: Hi, solved (!).  Can you add something about more complex case, for example `b VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL INDEX idx_tab_b gin (b gin_trgm_ops)` .. how to add more parameters  without repeat column name?

Comment: @PeterKrauss The example I provided is for SQL Server which does not support gin_trgm_ops.

Comment: Hi @LukaszSzozda  For syntax, perhaps you can try to transform any kind of complex `CREATE INDEX idxName ON tableName USING MethodName (fieldName optionName);` into syntax of *inline index definition*. PS: this question is about PostgreSQL not Microsoft-SQL-Server (see tags).

Comment: @PeterKrauss I am fully aware that this question is about PostgreSQL. I just gave you a proper name of this feature and show example how this could look like. Let's hope more RDBMS will support inlinde indexes in the future :)