# Remove uniqueness of index in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

In my PostgreSQL database I have a unique index created this way:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX <my_index> ON <my_table> USING btree (my_column)
```

Is there way to alter the index to remove the unique constraint? I looked at [ALTER INDEX documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-alterindex.html) but it doesn't seem to do what I need.

I know I can remove the index and create another one, but I'd like to find a better way, if it exists.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

You may be able to remove the unique `CONSTRAINT`, and not the `INDEX` itself.

Check your `CONSTRAINTS` via `select * from information_schema.table_constraints;`

Then if you find one, you should be able to drop it like:

`ALTER TABLE <my_table> DROP CONSTRAINT <constraint_name>`

Edit: a related issue is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922500/trouble-dropping-unique-constraint)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately there are no such constraints.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of this too, but checked it in Postgres... adding a unique index does not add a constraint to the table... it seems to be part of the index itself.

Comment: @dcsohl Yep. This is interesting, I looked into it and according to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239657/postgresql-can-you-create-an-index-in-the-create-table-definition#6239678) unique constraints can create indexes (but not the other way around)

Comment: @SergeyPotapov This answer does not solve the problem posed by your question. Could you revisit this question and select the [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38488663/2074605)?

Comment: Does not work - says that constraint does not exists.

Answer (score 54):

Assume you have the following:

```
Indexes:
    "feature_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id, f_id)
    "feature_unique" UNIQUE, btree (feature, f_class)
    "feature_constraint" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (feature, f_class)
```

To drop the UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, you would use [ALTER TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-altertable.html):

```
ALTER TABLE feature DROP CONSTRAINT feature_constraint;
```

To drop the PRIMARY KEY, you would also use [ALTER TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-altertable.html):

```
ALTER TABLE feature DROP CONSTRAINT feature_pkey;
```

To drop the UNIQUE [index], you would use [DROP INDEX](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-dropindex.html):

```
DROP INDEX feature_unique;
```

Comment: Does not work either. Index "does not exists" but cannot be created again because "relation "<name>" already exists:

Comment: @niedomnie That is a different problem. You need to check your schema for other relations (e.g. table names) with the same name. See related topic https://stackoverflow.com/a/8835441/2074605

Comment: will constraint occupy memory ?

Comment: @KIRANKUMARMATAM No, adding or removing a constraint will not have any direct, measurable impact on memory consumption in PostgreSQL. The only exception might be [deferred constraints](http://dbadailystuff.com/deferred-constraints-in-postgresql), which are applied at the end of a transaction, and that would be entirely dependent on your particular database.

Comment: @vallismortis thanks for reply what i meant here is space in db ?

Comment: @KIRANKUMARMATAM That depends entirely on your schema and the amount of data you have. You can check the sizes using [\di+ tbl*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46473305/2074605).

Answer (score 7):

I don't think it's possible... even in the pgAdmin III UI, if you try to edit a constraint created with your statement, the "Unique" box is greyed-out; you can't change it through the UI. Combined with your research on the ALTER INDEX docs, I'd say it can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

Searched for hours for the same quesiton and doesnt seem to get a right answer---- all the given answers just failed to work.

For not null, it also took me some time to find. Apparently for some reason, the majority-certified codes just dont work when I use it.

I got the not null version code, something like this

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
ALTER COLUMN column_want_to_remove_constriant
DROP NOT NULL
```

Sadly changing 'not null' to 'unique' doesnt work.

Comment: This seems not to be related to the question which asked for changing an index.