# PostgreSQL index size and value number

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to get statistics on indexes. I am looking for total values in an index and it size.

I can only find the size of all indexes on the table.
Table `pg_class` column `relpages` and `reltuples` shows the values for the table and not on specific index level.

In addition, function `pg_indexes_size` takes table name as an argument and returns the total index size for that table.

Is there a way to get the size and row number on index level?
I am using PostgreSQL 9.3.

Comment: `pg_stat_all_indexes`?..

Comment: pg_stat_all_indexes shows only statistics about read/fetch/scan and not the actual size and number of values in the index

Comment: yes, and `pg_indexes_size` that you mention shows the size indexes take on disk, not the "actual amount of data" - I thought you are ok with some aproximation? :)

Comment: pg_indexes_size shows the total index size of a table. I want the specific index size.

Comment: use `pg_table_size('index_name')` for individual index - but it will only show you the size on disk, not the amount of data

Comment: lots of example here : https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index_Maintenance

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is the query to retrieve info about:

- Total Size
- Total Size of all Indexes
- Table Size
- Index Size
- Estimated table row count

  ```
   SELECT i.relname "Table Name",indexrelname "Index Name",
   pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(relid)) As "Total Size",
   pg_size_pretty(pg_indexes_size(relid)) as "Total Size of all Indexes",
   pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(relid)) as "Table Size",
   pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(indexrelid)) "Index Size",
   reltuples::bigint "Estimated table row count"
   FROM pg_stat_all_indexes i JOIN pg_class c ON i.relid=c.oid 
   WHERE i.relname='uploads'
  ```

Maybe for someone it will be useful.

Answer (score 55):

`pg_table_size('index_name')` for individual index - but it only shows you the size on disk, not the number of *entries*.

`count(*)` to get the exact current number of rows

`sum(pg_column_size(column_name)) from table_name` for estimations on column data size.

You can try something like:

```
t=# \di+ tbl*
                                    List of relations
 Schema |   Name    | Type  |  Owner   | Table |  Size  | Description
--------+-----------+-------+----------+-------+--------+-------------
 public | tbl_pkey  | index | postgres | tbl   | 156 MB |
 public | tbl_unpic | index | postgres | tbl   | 46 MB  |
 public | tbl_x1    | index | postgres | tbl   | 57 MB  |
(3 rows)

t=# \dt+ tbl
                        List of relations
 Schema | Name | Type  |  Owner   | Size  | Description
--------+------+-------+----------+-------+-------------
 public | tbl  | table | postgres | 78 MB |
(1 row)

t=# select pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('tbl'));
 pg_size_pretty
----------------
 337 MB
(1 row)

t=# select 78+57+46+156;
 ?column?
----------
      337
(1 row)
```

and to check how `psql` gets the individual index size, run it with `psql -E`.

and once again - functions above work with size it takes on disk - it may/(may not) be extremely different from real amount of data. vacuuming helps here

---

**update**

I don't know where you directly get the number of "rows" in an index, thus I can only offer indirect way. Eg let me have a partial index, so the "number of rows" in the index is different from the number of rows in the table. I can check estimations with EXPLAIN (of course you have to repeat the `WHERE` clause for that) checking the `rows=66800` in `Index Only Scan using` gives me an idea on the number of rows in that index (actually it is `rows=64910` which you can get by `explain analyze` or just running `count(*)`). I can't find relevant info in `pg_stats` - maybe there's some formula. I don't know.

Comment: Vao Tsun, Thanks a lot for your answer but maybe I do not fully understand Pg index maintenance.  I run the following: create table stg.test_index_size as 
select t.id, case when t.id<25000 then 'small' else 'high' end as flag 
from  generate_series(1,50000) as t(id);
create unique index idx_id on stg.test_index_size(id);
create  index idx_flag on stg.test_index_size(flag);
vacuum analyze stg.test_index_size; Now when I checking the size of the the two indexes  with pg_table_size(quote_ident(indexrelname)::text) , I am getting the same result. I expected the flag index will be smaller

Comment: fair point regarding stat table - editted answer - thank you. regarding the other - better ask a new question I suppose

Comment: Also pg_stat_all_indexes does not show estimate row number of the index but rather only idx_scan,idx_tup_read and idx_tup_fetch. I expect to get idx_id 50000 and idx_flag =2

Answer (score 54):

This sql will give you detailed info for table and index size

```
SELECT
   relname  as table_name,
   pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(relid)) As "Total Size",
   pg_size_pretty(pg_indexes_size(relid)) as "Index Size",
   pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(relid)) as "Actual Size"
   FROM pg_catalog.pg_statio_user_tables 
ORDER BY pg_total_relation_size(relid) DESC;
```

Comment: Note that "Actual Size" above means "Table data without TOAST used for long columns". Instead of that you might want to use `pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size(relid)) as "Data Size",` which would give you Data Size + Index Size = Total Size. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70397779/1317406 for more information.