# How to correctly remove index uniqueness in postresql?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have unique index which was created like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX payment_idem_key_idx ON public.payment USING btree (contract_id, idempotency_key)
```

I want to remove the `UNIQUE` keyword from this index. How do I do it correctly? Should I somehow alter the index? Or should I drop it and then create a new one without the unique keyword? What would be the best practice in order not to lose anything.

I checked [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514759/remove-uniqueness-of-index-in-postgresql), but the answer didn't really help me, because my unique index is not in constraint list. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You will have to drop and re-create the index.

Comment: You should always question dropping unique. While dropping and recreating the index will not loose any data, be very sure you are not loosing a business requirement by allowing duplicates.