# Set partial unique index on table creation in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, constraints, indices

When defining unique indices in PostgreSQL you have two options:

- Define unique index using constraint with the table via a single statement
- Define index later after table is created using separate `CREATE INDEX` statement

However, when it comes to [unique partial indices](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/indexes-partial.html#INDEXES-PARTIAL-EX3), is it possible to create one with the table using single statement or do I have to use a separate statement?

I would prefer to define all the indices with the table.

Comment: This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239657/postgresql-can-you-create-an-index-in-the-create-table-definition is a bit old but it still appears to be the case that you can't create an index other than simple constraints during the table creation statement.